# SWT - Drawing a Moving Image Over Tiles

Tags: java, swt

I've been experimenting with different ways of moving a image over a grid of tiles for a game, but I've been unable to get a working implementation.

First I tried using a grid layout to hold a bunch of Tiles that extended Canvas and drew themselves. This drew the tiles nicely, however it seems that I am unable to draw my Player object on top of them. Originally, the Player also extended Canvas and I intended to have the widget on top of the tiles. It seems like this is impossible.

I then tried to have the Tile simply extend nothing, and just hold the image. I then hold each Tile in a 2D array and draw each Tile by a nested for loop, using the int from the for loop, multiplied by the image size, to draw Tile's Image. I put this code in a PaintListener inside of my constructor for my Map class that extended Canvas and dropped my Map onto my Shell in a Fill layout, but the PaintListener never gets called (I tested with a print statement).

What implementation could I use to draw the Tiles at the start of the game, then allow me to control the movement of my Player image?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar.

Using a `PaintListener` I get the calls when the Widget needs to be repainted. In my paint function, I loop over a tile array (wrapped in a `World` class) and draw all tiles. Afterwards I use the same technique with a `worldObjects` array/class:

```
public class WorldWidget extends Canvas {

    WorldWidget() {
        addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                WorldWidget.this.paintControl(e);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        GC gc = e.gc;
        for (short y = 0; y < world.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (short x = 0; x < world.getWidth(); x++) {
                final ITile tile = world.getTile(x, y);
                final Image image = ImageCache.getImage(tile);
                gc.drawImage(image, x * tileSize, y * tileSize);
            }
        }

        // Here is used a similar loop, to draw world objects
    }
}
```

This is obviously a condensed code example, as the class is part of an editor and reacts on mouse clicks and movement amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

When I did a tile based simulation while ago I did it this way:
I had 2 layers of the tile map - one for the terrain and second for the units.
The map itself was represented by a `JPanel`.
So roughly you got this for the `JPanel`:

```
        public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
                // create an offscreen buffer to render the map
                if (buffer == null) {
                    buffer = new BufferedImage(SimulationMap.MAP_WIDTH, SimulationMap.MAP_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                }
                Graphics g = buffer.getGraphics();

                g.clearRect(0, 0, SimulationMap.MAP_WIDTH, SimulationMap.MAP_HEIGHT);

                // cycle through the tiles in the map drawing the appropriate
                // image for the terrain and units where appropriate
                for (int x = 0; x < map.getWidthInTiles(); x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < map.getHeightInTiles(); y++) {
                        if (map.getTerrain(x, y) != null) {
                            g.drawImage(tiles[map.getTerrain(x, y).getType()], x * map.getTILE_WIDTH(), y * map.getTILE_HEIGHT(), null);
                        }
                    }
                }

               if (map.getSimulationUnits() != null) {
                   for (Unit unit : map.getSimulationUnits()) {
                    g.drawImage(tiles[unit.getUnitType()], (int) Math.round(unit.getActualXCor() * map.getTILE_WIDTH()), (int) Math.round(unit.getActualYCor() * map.getTILE_HEIGHT()),
                            null);
                   }
                }    

    // ...
// draw the buffer
        graphics.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
        }
```

Logic:

```
private Terrain[][] terrain = new Terrain[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
/** The unit in each tile of the map */
private Unit[][] units = new Unit[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

Then you have your game loop where you update the position of the units and other things, basically `render()` and `update()` the game. Check the links I've provided below.

*NOTE*

1. Since you are making a simple game [this post](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,24220.0) about making game loops will be definitely useful for you. This hopefully also answer your question about moving the object on the map.
2. [This site](http://www.cokeandcode.com/index.html?page=tutorials/tilemap1) will be also very helpful since you will probably need to detect collision at some point too.